# NON JS youtube popup (plain html?)

Tags: html, css, youtube, popup

Does anybody know of a non Javascript youtube video pop up. I have a button on my homepage which I want to open a pop up with a youtube video inside.

Thanks guys

this is my link

```
 <a href="http://youtu.be/krlR2-YGk4sI" target="_blank"><span class="cta floatL">through the eyes of a bigsmile advert</span><span class="playIco floatL"></span></a>
```

this is my iframe

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/krlR2-YGk4sI?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

I just need to find a way to make it pop up in the center of the screen like a fancybox, without javascript. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

no i dont think there is a method without using JS but it is very simple with JS for a piece like this. you should just be able to place the popup in a div and then use CSS to make it hidden then on the button click a JS function that will bring it to the top.
Hope this helps :)

```
    <div id='PopUp' style='display:none;'>
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
    <button onclick='showPopUp()'>click Me</button>
        <script>
            function showPopUp()
            {
                document.getElementById('PopUp').style.display = 'block';
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: This did not work when pasted into dreamweaver and tested. Thank you for the thought though

Comment: Worked fine for me did you run it on a local host? And did you put your iframe information in the <iframe></iframe>?

Comment: Also your iframe information is a mess try using <iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/krlR2-YGk4sI?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>